# How does MTR work in detail? Shouldn't packet loss be observed to increase linearly?

Tags: packet, traceroute

If so, how come do we see packet loss be distributed unevenly among hops? That is, if there is 5 percent loss in the first hop, the following hops, should start out with 95 percent of the packets remaining. And if there are further packet loss in the subsequent hops, shouldn't the graph of the overall MTR look linear in its totality, as each subsequent hop would start out with fewer and fewer packets while packets traverse across these gateway routers?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 cases when you seeing a MTR result.

- Single node with high loss%.

This means nothing at all in most cases. we can not conclude that the node with high loss% is malfunctioning, because all the ohter nodes after it perform well by showing low loss%. Perhaps it's limited by ISP, by its CPU or by some software-define-function such that it's under limited function to reply ICMP message.

- Monotone Increasing loss%, started from a node

This means the start node may be malfunctioning or occurs traffic congestion or something wrong else.

Seems that you have described the `1st` case.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search gives me the Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software) . An excerpt from it : `The tool is often used for network troubleshooting. By showing a list of routers traversed, and the average round-trip time as well as packet loss to each router, it allows users to identify links between two given routers responsible for certain fractions of the overall latency or packet loss through the network. This can help identify network overuse problems.` Does this help answer your question? And most of all have you read the documentation?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I did read the wikipedia, however, I was not able to find any references to why the packet loss does not exhibit linear loss. I also couldn't find an explanation to what causes uneven packet loss distribution, which is why I had to ask this question here.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all. You've just linked a Wikipedia page (which also doesn't really answer the question)

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer from [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-does-mtr-work-in-detail-shouldn%27t-packet-loss-be-observed-to-increase-linearly-4175677451/#post6136906):

> It sends ICMP packets with increasing TTL, so that it gets a response
> from the first router, the second router etc. until the destination
> host.
>
> > if so, how come do we see packet loss be distributed unevenly among
> > hops?
>
> Because the percentage of packets without reply differs from router to
> router.
>
> > That is, if there is 5 percent loss in the first hop, the following
> > hops, should start out with 95 percent of the packets remaining.
>
> Yes, but mtr measures packet loss between router n and router n+1. It
> doesn't accumulate losses.
>
> There are several tutorials out there. I found this one useful
> (haven't read it all yet):
> [https://www.linode.com/docs/networki...sues-with-mtr/](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/diagnosing-network-issues-with-mtr/).